# What algorithm does cvxpy actually use to solve SDP problems with the constraint form $\sum_i E_iXE_i^T \succ B$

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, python, semidefinite-programming, cvxpy

<sub>[Crossposted](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/41459) on Computational Science SE</sub>

---

CVXPY is a famous software as a solver for optimization problems.Nowadays I use it to run a program presented in a [paper](https://opus.lib.uts.edu.au/bitstream/10453/127333/4/p818-ying.pdf),the Example 7.1,and the program runs as follows (I haven't found out how to insert my codes here,otherwise I would post them) all matrices are $4 \times 4$: 
$O_0$ and $O_3$ are varibles,the target function is $\min\text{tr}(O_0+O_3)$ and the constraints are :
$O_0 \succeq 0,O_3 \succeq 0, O_0 \preceq I, O_3 \preceq I,\left( \begin{matrix}0&0.707&0&0.707\\0&0&0&0\\0&0.707&0&-0.707\\0&0&0&0 \end{matrix}\right)O_0\left( \begin{matrix}0&0&0&0\\0.707&0&0.707&0\\0&0&0&0\\0.707&0&-0.707&0 \end{matrix}\right)+\left(\begin{matrix}0&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1 \end{matrix}\right)O_3\left(\begin{matrix}0&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1 \end{matrix}\right)\succeq\left(\begin{matrix}1&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0 \end{matrix}\right)\\
\left( \begin{matrix}0&0.707&0&0.707\\0&0&0&0\\0&0.707&0&-0.707\\0&0&0&0 \end{matrix}\right)O_0\left( \begin{matrix}0&0&0&0\\0.707&0&0.707&0\\0&0&0&0\\0.707&0&-0.707&0 \end{matrix}\right)-O_0+\left(\begin{matrix}0&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1 \end{matrix}\right)O_3\left(\begin{matrix}0&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1 \end{matrix}\right)\succeq 0$.
The output of the program is: the optimal value is 1.9999988116689815,and $O_0=O_3=\left(\begin{matrix}0&0&0&0\\0&0.5&0&0.5\\0&0&0&0\\0&0.5&0&0.5 \end{matrix}\right)$.
It is not hard to see that the constraints are all in the form of $\sum\limits_i\sum\limits_j A_{ij}X_iA_{ij}^T\preceq\text{(or}\succeq\text{)}B$,where $X_i$ are variables.However for SDP algorithms(such as interior point method and cutting plane method) what we are dealing with are SDP is in the form of the standard or the dual form.However the above CVXPY solver can directly give the output without converting to standard form or dual form,so I wonder what algorithm does CVXPY actually take.I have read the [guidebook](https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/) of CVXPY but haven't found out where it is mentioned.I am interested in this problem because I once studied such [SDP problems](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4409901/converting-to-standard-forms-of-semidefinite-programming)

Comment: This is not really a math question, maybe you could try https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/ or another more relevant place?

Comment: It is a mathematics question.

Comment: I don't know what CVX uses, but you could use projections on the space of PSD matrices to implement something to solve the above.

Comment: I added an answer on the crosspost https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/41459/what-algorithm-does-cvxpy-actually-use-to-solve-semidefinite-programs-with-the-c/43086#43086 

Not sure if that means I should duplicate the answer here or not but have a look there.